# How do I optimize query where searching for 'is not null' on either of two linked tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_first_table a   -- > 1 million records
INNER JOIN my_second_table b     -- > 1 million records
    on a.id = b.a_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_third_table c -- > 1 million records
    on a.id = c.a_id
WHERE   b.my_column_x IS NOT NULL
OR      c.my_column_y IS NOT NULL
AND     b.start_date  > isnull(@startdate, '17530101')
AND     b.end_date    < isnull(@enddate, '99991231')
```

`my_column_x` and `my_column_y` are both indexed, however as I'm doing an `OR IS NOT NULL` across both of these columns, neither index is being used, and the query is extremely slow.

I'm also doing a date range check. `b.start_date` and `b.end_date` are both `datetime` columns, and are indexed. The query accepts inputs where both the start and end dates can be null or a specified datetime.

How can I optimize the query? I'm thinking there must be a way I can do some kind of separate sub-selects for `IS NOT NULL` on `my_second_table.my_column_x` and `my_third_table.my_column_y` then combine those sub-selects in order to be able to join in the way I'm trying to do in the original query, so that the indexes on `b.my_column_x` and `b.my_column_y` are used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are different ways to replace ISNULL() in a WHERE clause that uses only literal values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168276/what-are-different-ways-to-replace-isnull-in-a-where-clause-that-uses-only-lit)

Comment: Do you know that without parenetheses, your query is parsed and executed as `WHERE ( b.my_column_x IS NOT NULL )  OR (  c.my_column_y IS NOT NULL AND b.start_date  > ... AND b.end_date < ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Biggest mistake is you are using `*` in `Select`.

> Do you require column from all three table in your resultset ?

Once you should try this,

```
if(@startdate is null)
set @startdate='17530101'

if(@enddate is null)
set @enddate='99991231'

SELECT * FROM dbo.my_first_table a   -- > 1 million records
INNER JOIN dbo.my_second_table b     -- > 1 million records
    on a.id = b.a_id and b.my_column_x IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.my_third_table c -- > 1 million records
    on a.id = c.a_id and c.my_column_y IS NOT NULL
WHERE   
 b.[start_date]  > @startdate
AND     b.[end_date]    < @enddate
```